# Voice Recognition Without Dialog Android

Tags: android, cordova, voice-recognition

I an developing an app which requires voice recognition using phonegap. Everything works fine but when i press the voice recognition button a default android dialog comes up. I want to remove that and have the voice recognition run without it. Can You Please Help ?

[image]